# iOS forum setup

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

If I wanted to have a user forum in my app would this be a way to set it up?

MySQL DB for the backend 
PHP page for the web service
NSURLConnection to talk and receive from the web service

it would be fairly simple, plain text.

I'm sure there's a gazillion ways to set this up but this is the rout I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to have a user forum *in* your app, you're going to access a user forum *from* your app. So any way you want to set up the forum on your server, including the one you suggest, will work fine provided there's a way to connect to it from iOS.

You can use `NSURLConnection` to access the forum, of course, but that class just manages the actual connection. You might find it easier to use a `UIWebView` as a mini-browser in your app, and simply point the web view at the appropriate URL.

Comment: Semantic point taken. : D And I probably should have (after reading your response) correctly stated this as a "comments" section on the app content (it's a mag). So technically not a forum but programmatically similar. So, given that new info, if the article is in a UIScrollView, content is a UITextView, there's some other bells and whistles, would you still put a UIWebView beneath the UITextView for comments or would you consider pulling in XML/JSON and parsing it?

Comment: I don't think either way is better or more correct than the other -- it just depends on what your server provides. If it provides the comments as XML or JSON, then you don't need much more than a simple NSURLConnection to get the data, plus code in the app to display it appropriately. If the server is running some forum package that gives you web content, it'd be easier to use a web view. I'm not telling you anything you probably don't already know here, but your question seems more like a request for validation, so: yes, that should work, go for it.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, your right, though I was less looking for validation and more hoping not to get a 'are you a moron' response. : D Thanks for commenting.